# CSS - Specific Outline

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I would like to create an specific outline for a box using css.

Something like this image:
[image: Specific Outline]

Please, any help? :(

Comment: outline or border ??

Comment: before and after or bg image png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at gradients, background-clip and background-size:

example possible http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aZbrEQ

```css
div {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 40px;
  /* set offset here for border corners */
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) top left no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) top left no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) top right no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) top right no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) bottom right no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) bottom right no-repeat, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  /* color receive 
  background-clip:content-box; 
  so it is not drawn on padding areas */
  background-clip: border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, content-box;
  background-size: 2px 60px, 80px 2px;
  /* here give length and thickness of border corners */
  color: white;
}
p,
h2 {
  padding: 1em;
  margin:0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/6);
  background-size: cover
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please add a h2 and a span to your example? Thank you!

Comment: @Eusthace i updated the snippet and moved p css to div (the wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Just to prove how simple your question is.
`::before` and `::after` hides parts of the border.
`z-index` for overlay.

```css
.dirt {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(251, 145, 156, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(231, 0, 0, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dirt > span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  padding: 25px;
}
.dirt::after,
.dirt::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(251, 145, 156, 1);
  /*same color*/
}
.dirt::before {
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: -2px;
  /*border-width*/
  right: -2px;
  /*border-width*/
}
.dirt::after {
  top: -2px;
  /*border-width*/
  bottom: -2px;
  /*border-width*/
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<p>An example: (do not use)</p>
<div class="dirt">
  <span>My little dirt text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The case that they want the outline to have an offset and be more separated from the box. Just like the photo I've shown before...:( Any help about this?

Comment: A moment please :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Not need anymore i see, if needed any help, feel free to ask ;-)